# How to not use a few pixels for anything in GrabCut

Tags: c++, opencv, image-segmentation

Currently, in the grabcut function available, I have to mark all pixels one of the four variables - GC_BGD, GC_FGD, GC_PR_BGD and GC_PR_FGD.

What should I do if I have a few pixels for which I can't decide any of the afore-mentioned labels. The problem is that if I mark them as GC_PR_FGD or GC_PR_BGD, they are being used to train the respective colour models and hence the grabcut is biased to mark them as the labels I provide them.

Is there anyway I can bypass the assertion that the pixels should have any of the four values in the mask?

Comment: In my experience, I have always placed unknown pixels to GC_PR_BGD. YOu could also use different initialization methods, mask isn't the only one.

Comment: But it seems like any kind of initialisation method for Grabcut marks each and every pixel as some label (implicitly or otherwise). I was hoping there will be a quicker work around, other than making changes in grabcut's code itself.